# Java SSLHandshakeException on one server but not another?

Tags: java, ssl

In an attempt to debug this SSL issue that came up on one of our servers recently I wrote a very simple program to connect to an SSL site in our intranet.

```
    URL authURL = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String url = "https://our.server:443";

    try {
        authURL = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) 
                authURL.openConnection(); 
        conn.setDoOutput(false);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.connect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException urlEx) {
        urlEx.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try { br.close(); }
            catch (IOException e) {}
        }//if
    }//finally
```

This code fails with SSLHandshakeException on one of our servers, but the same exact code works without issue on another server.  I ran the programs with SSL debugging enabled and here are results of each server

**WORKING SERVER - SLES 11.3, Java IBM 1.6.0 64-bit**

```
... no IV used for this cipher
main, WRITE: SSLv3 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
JsseJCE:  Using cipher RC4 from provider TBD via init
CipherBox:  Using cipher RC4 from provider from init IBMJCE version 1.2
JsseJCE:  Using MAC SslMacSHA1 from provider TBD via init
MAC:  Using MessageDigest SslMacSHA1 from provider IBMJCE version 1.2
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 101, 62, 81, 35, 

13, 178, 124, 13, 43, 0, 5, 248, 32, 15, 39, 244, 97, 96, 98, 227, 1 8, 172, 226, 53, 71, 218, 210, 21, 72, 85, 44, 130, 175, 194, 228, 34 }
***
main, WRITE: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 60
main, READ: SSLv3 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
JsseJCE:  Using cipher RC4 from provider TBD via init
CipherBox:  Using cipher RC4 from provider from init IBMJCE version 1.2
JsseJCE:  Using MAC SslMacSHA1 from provider TBD via init
MAC:  Using MessageDigest SslMacSHA1 from provider IBMJCE version 1.2
main, READ: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 60
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 160, 27, 2, 24, 10, 15, 205, 204, 241, 225, 183, 150, 243, 244, 43, 107, 40, 112, 173  42, 122, 139, 225, 16, 33, 168, 255, 184, 23, 18, 69, 103, 19, 68, 182, 139 }
***
cached session [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA]
%% Cached client session: [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA]
main, WRITE: SSLv3 Application Data, length = 213
main, READ: SSLv3 Application Data, length = 402
```

**NOT WORKING SERVER: Windows 7, Java JDK 1.6.0_39**

```
   ... no IV used for this cipher
main, WRITE: SSLv3 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 235, 130, 222, 201, 56, 225, 104, 77, 87, 210, 63, 16, 196, 223, 123, 231, 173, 146, 111, 102, 99, 214, 20, 244, 138, 79, 217, 140, 10, 61, 167, 9, 222, 95, 247, 208 }
***
main, WRITE: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 60
main, received EOFException: error
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
main, SEND SSLv3 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
main, WRITE: SSLv3 Alert, length = 22
main, called closeSocket()
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1203)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1230)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1214)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:133)
    at test.Main.main(Main.java:43)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:333)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:863)
    ... 7 more
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what I can do to get this simple code working on my Windows 7 machine?  I have been at this all day and pretty lost at this point.  Thanks for any help!

**Update - Requested openssl output**

**Working server**

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 /C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=2 /C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
verify return:1
depth=1 /C=US/O=Thawte, Inc./CN=Thawte SGC CA - G2
verify return:1
depth=0 /C=US/ST=California/L=Riverside/O=University of California-Riverside/OU=Computing and Communication/CN=example.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Riverside/O=University of California-Riverside/OU=Computing and Communication/CN=example.com
   i:/C=US/O=Thawte, Inc./CN=Thawte SGC CA - G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=Thawte, Inc./CN=Thawte SGC CA - G2
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
 2 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
 3 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
---
```

**Not working server**

```
    CONNECTED(0000018C)
depth=3 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = Class 3 Public Primary Certification
Authority
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Riverside/O=University of California-Riverside/OU=Computing and Communication/CN=example.com
   i:/C=US/O=Thawte, Inc./CN=Thawte SGC CA - G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=Thawte, Inc./CN=Thawte SGC CA - G2
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc.
 - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
 2 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc.
 - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
 3 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
---
```

Comment: @jww  Updated with openssl output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different results are likely because the the trust store on each machine is slightly different. Here I'm assuming you are running your client locally on the server so each uses the JVM available locally.

But it does not explain the odd looking chain...

```
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Riverside/O=University of California-Riverside/OU=Computing and Communication/CN=example.com
   i:/C=US/O=Thawte, Inc./CN=Thawte SGC CA - G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=Thawte, Inc./CN=Thawte SGC CA - G2
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc.
 - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
 2 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc.
 - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
 3 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
```

Certificate 0 is the server's certificate, and obviously it must be present.

Certificate 1 is the intermediate required to build the chain. The server must send it too. It must send it to avoid the ["which directory" problem](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Transport_Layer_Protection_Cheat_Sheet#Rule_-_Always_Provide_All_Needed_Certificates). Its a well known problem in PKI, and it means a client does not know which directory to go to for a missing certificate.

I can't find Certificate 1 at [Thawte root certificates](http://www.thawte.com/roots/). Certificate 1's issuer is `VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5`.

Certificate 2 is `VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5`. From experience, I know that's a CA, and I'm not sure why it claims to have an issuer.

You can download `VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5` from [Verisign Root Certifcates](http://www.symantec.com/page.jsp?id=roots). Its filename is `VeriSign-Class-3-Public-Primary-Certification-Authority-G5.pem`. Then:

```
$ openssl x509 -in VeriSign-Class-3-Public-Primary-Certification-Authority-G5.pem -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            18:da:d1:9e:26:7d:e8:bb:4a:21:58:cd:cc:6b:3b:4a
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=VeriSign, Inc., OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only, CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov  8 00:00:00 2006 GMT
            Not After : Jul 16 23:59:59 2036 GMT
        Subject: C=US, O=VeriSign, Inc., OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only, CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:af:24:08:08:29:7a:35:9e:60:0c:aa:e7:4b:3b:
                    ...
                    25:15
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.12: 
                0_.].[0Y0W0U..image/gif0!0.0...+..............k...j.H.,{..0%.#http://logo.verisign.com/vslogo.gif
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                7F:D3:65:A7:C2:DD:EC:BB:F0:30:09:F3:43:39:FA:02:AF:33:31:33
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         93:24:4a:30:5f:62:cf:d8:1a:98:2f:3d:ea:dc:99:2d:bd:77:
         ...
         a8:ed:63:6a
```

Notice its a CA: the subject and issuer are the same, there's a bacic constraints with `CA:true` marked as critical, etc.

So I *think* you may be using an old Verisign certificate. It might even be expired. But you have access to it, so only you can tell.

Now, here's where it gets really odd: Certificate 3 and `Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority`. Its a CA too, but its not certifying anything.

So, I would do the following:

1. Remove Certificate 2 from the chain
2. Remove Certificate 3 from the chain
3. Add `VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5` to the trust store
4. Test both servers with OpenSSL

To test: first, download `VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5` from [Verisign Root Certifcates](http://www.symantec.com/page.jsp?id=roots). Its filename is `VeriSign-Class-3-Public-Primary-Certification-Authority-G5.pem`.

Second run `openssl s_client` against each server (command shown below). Include the `CAfile` option to specify the Verisign trust anchor. Using the required trust anchor, it should finish with: `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -CAfile VeriSign-Class-3-Public-Primary-Certification-Authority-G5.pem
...
Start Time: 1407273676
Timeout   : 300 (sec)
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

`openssl s_client` will remove Java from the loop, and allow you to verify you have a "known good" baseline for testing further in Java. But I suspect you have an old Verisign Root in the misbehaving server's certificate store, or you are missing a required root in the misbehaving server's certificate store, or both.

Comment: I just got word from the system admin's that they did update their certificates within the last few days.  So your theory on my machine having an old certificate might be accurate.  I can't seem to find the openssl commands to run on my local machine to remove Certificate 2 & 3 from the chain.  I'm guessing these are cached on my machine somehow and I need to remove them correct?

Comment: Thanks for that great explanation, i learned something today!

Comment: *"...run on my local machine to remove Certificate 2 & 3 from the chain"* - that's probably in the the web server's keystore or the web server's configuration file. If its in the keystore, then use `keytool` to delete a certificate. If its a configuration file, its likely a concatenation of PEM files (`-----BEGIN CERT-----` and friends). Just remove the unwanted certs. Use `openssl x509 -in <cert> -text -noout` to print them and see what they are.